# How to use joins in Rails with squeel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, squeel

How to use joins or other ways to let me use the where query to compare other conditions in another model?

Model relation

```
class SonyAlarmLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sony_alarm_test

class SonyAlarmTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sony_alarm_bugs, :dependent => :destroy
```

It works, but returns me the columns of the `SonyAlarmTest`, I wanna the columns of `sony_alarm_logs`

```
SonyAlarmTest.joins{:sony_alarm_logs}
.where{ sony_alarm_logs.name =~ event_name }
```

It failed, get the `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'sony_alarm_tests' was not found on SonyAlarmLog; perhaps you misspelled it?` Error

```
SonyAlarmLog.joins(:sony_alarm_tests)
.where{ name =~ event_name }
```

### UPDATE (Fix: it should use the singular name)

But still got `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: firmware_version` error

I thought it may be mis-use of squeel syntax ?

```
SonyAlarmLog.joins(:sony_alarm_test)
.where{ name =~ event_name }
.where{ utc_time.gt (my{utc_time} + TIME_CORRECTION) }
.where{ sony_alarm_tests.round.eq(my{sony_alarm_test.round}) }
.where{ sony_alarm_tests.ip =~ my{sony_alarm_test.ip} }                            
.where{ sony_alarm_tests.firmware_version =~ my{sony_alarm_test.firmware_version} }
```

Comment: Try with singular `SonyAlarmLog`, because that is your model name, not the pluralized `SonyAlarmLogs`.

Comment: @vee sorry for the typos, I corrected it.

Comment: The `:sony_alarm_tests` in your `joins` also needs to be singular `:sony_alarm_test` which is the `belongs_to :sony_alarm_test` in your `SonyAlarmLog` model.

Comment: @vee Thanks for your help, do you know how to use the where clause with joins

Comment: Please see my answer below.  There needed to be a few changes in the syntax (basing this on the linked documentation of squeel).

Answer (score 0):

Following up to the comments...  As per the documention of [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel), you could write your query as:

```
SonyAlarmLog.joins{:sony_alarm_test}.
  where{ 
    (name =~ event_name) & 
    (utc_time.gt (my{utc_time} + TIME_CORRECTION)) & 
    (sony_alarm_test.round.eq(my{sony_alarm_test.round})) &
    (sony_alarm_test.ip =~ my{sony_alarm_test.ip}) &                            
    (sony_alarm_test.firmware_version =~ my{sony_alarm_test.firmware_version})
  }
```

The reason you are getting the error is likely because of the either `sony_alarm_tests.firmware_version` or `sony_alam_test.firmware_version`.  Note one of them is plural and the other one is singular.  You want to be using "singular" version here as the association is "belongs_to".